# If X has a dense subset, does that imply that X is closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume X has a dense subset Y. Then every point in X is a limit point in Y, and so the union of Y and it's closure contains X. Therefore X must be closed. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The interval $]0,1[$ has a dense subset, for instance $]0,1[ \cap \mathbb{Q}$, but is not closed.

Comment: Clear and precise, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> the union of Y and its closure contains X

Sure *(incidentally, the closure of a set contains the set itself already)*. But so what? All that means is that we have $$Y\subseteq X\subseteq cl(Y).$$ But unless we know $Y=cl(Y)$ we can't "close the gap" to argue $X=cl(Y)$ and hence be closed.

On the other hand, the above *does* show that a set with a *closed* dense subset is itself closed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference. I was working with a problem where I had a subspace C of X which contained a dense set consisting of the closed span of an orthonormal basis B. I wanted to make the argument that C would then be closed in X, and that C was in fact equal to the closure of Span(B).